# Want to dynamically place decimal point in given 18 digit string(representing amount)

Tags: mule

I have two variables i.e. amount(18 char) and precision(2 digits). I want to put the decimal point in amount based on precision value.
Lets say amount= **100000000000000000** and precision=2, then using dwl I want to convert amount as **1000000000000000.00**

Please note I don't want to use global function due to performance issue.

I tried it using amount/100. this gave me exponential **1.0E15**.

dwl-

```
{
amount :100000000000000000 as :string /100
}
```

Expected output is `{ amount : 1000000000000000.00 }`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I used below implementation and now this gives me exactly what I want. **I just need to divide the number by 10(or 100 or 1000 etc based on precision value) before formatting output.**

```
%dw 1.0
    %output application/json
    ---
    {
        "amt" : "100123456789123456789" /"1000" as :string {format: "#"}
    }
```

output received:

> {   "amt": 100123456789123456.789
>       }

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the following documentation on MuleSoft:

https://support.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-format-numbers-in-DataWeave

https://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev/training-talks/how-to-format-numbers-in-dataweave/

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
{
amount :100000000000000000 as :string {format: "#.00"}
}
```

yields:

`{"amount": "100000000000000000.00"}`

Comment: Please mark the question as answered by checking the green check mark next to my answer. Thanks!

Comment: above solution works in case I want to format number with precision.
What if I don't have precision already there and I want to put precision based on some random value. i.e. I want to place decimal point at position 2 for number 123, I expect number returned as 1.23.